# Is there any canon evidence that FN-2187 actually worked in sanitation?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

Finn tells Han that he worked in "Sanitation" on Starkiller.

```
FINN
The flooding tunnels are over that
ridge. We'll get in that way.
HAN
What was your job when you were based
here?
FINN
Sanitation.
HAN
Sanitation? Then how do you know
how to disable the shields?
FINN
I don't. I'm just here to get Rey
```

It just occurs to me - the "I was in sanitation" line given to Han seems to be the only actual canon evidence of "Sanitation" job.

**But was it the truth"?!?!**

Finn is always trying to create a positive impression of himself with the Resistance, from the get-go:

- He tells Poe that he's rescuing him because that's the "Right thing to do" (with Poe quickly seeing through the fib: "You need a pilot!")
- He tells Rey that he's Resistance (she buys that because she's a romantic 19 year old still playing with X-Wing pilot helmet)
- He tells Han that he's Resistance (that one lasts about a minute - Han was not a romantic 19 year old even at 19 :)

In reality, we know that he was 1% of his class, model stormtrooper cadet, personally groomed for promotion by Captain Phasma ([Evidence of that: #1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113379/976); [Evidence #2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113346/976)).

However, I am pretty sure telling Han "Hey, I was 1% of my class, model stormtrooper cadet, groomed for promotion by Captain Phasma"  isn't high on his list of brand management plans.

Far better to pretend to be a lowly "sanitation" worker than top-flight cadet that he really was.

So, my question is - **do we have any direct canon evidence proving that the "sanitation" job was real and not a fib to make himself look better to Han/Resistance**?

Knowing where trash compactor was isn't direct evidence, though it is circumstantial one.

Comment: Only that he gave his word on being what he says that he is after beginning to trust them

Comment: I just assumed it was something he said so he didn't have to tell them he was a storm trooper.

Comment: It seems to me that his knowledge that flood-control tunnels could be used to access the interior of the base is intended to indicate that he was, indeed, assigned to sanitation, and in the course of those duties learned about this weak point which the base's designers hadn't considered. Without any indication that the First Order specifically relieves high-performing cadets of undignified duties, there's no reason to think he wouldn't have a sanitation job just because he's at the top of his class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it says that he did in the [Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary).

[image]
<sub><sup>As part of his training rotation, FN-2187 also logged many hours on

 sanitation detail, dirty work that nonetheless needed doing.</sup></sub>

As well as in the new canon novel [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Finn's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Finn%27s_Story)

> *After years of training, FN-2187 had itched for some real action. Like
>   other stormtrooper cadets, **he’d rotated through several lower-level
>   duties, including a janitorial assignment,** but he hadn’t seen any real
>   live-fire action yet. Then one day their trainer and leader, Captain
>   Phasma, told him that they would be deployed. So FN-2187 gathered his
>   men, double-checked their gear, and headed to their transport.*

Comment: They really should rename "Visual Dictionary" in "plothole coverage dictionary" :)

Comment: @DVK - That special honour goes to the Junior novelisation.

Comment: I know the Visual Dictionary is canon, but IMHO this doesn't jive with the _Before The Awakening_ novel. In that, at the start he's still in training, and at the end of his story they're on their way to rendezvous with Kylo Ren, presumably to then head to Jakku. There's nothing to indicate he's ever been on Starkiller Base, let alone worked sanitation there.

Comment: Considering he also literally said it in the movie, I wouldn't call that a plothole.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe - There's some additional detail in the new "Finn's Story" book.

Answer (score 6):

One minor additional canon hint:

When Han, Chewie and Finn capture Phasma, and they need to decide what to do with her, Han asks at around 1:39:25:

> Is there a garbage chute? A compactor?

And Finn answers with an evil smile - and with the confidence of someone who knows:

> Yeah, there is.

So, he speaks from experience and knowledge?

Comment: An excellent point.